# How to pass parameters to a function that is the argument of another function

Tags: r, function, parameters

I have an objective function f(x, d), where x is the a vector of two variables (x1, x2) and d is a Nx2 matrix of points,that is given. f(x) is a distance function calculating some compount distance from x to all the points in d.

I'm trying to create a Gradient Descent function for calculating the minimum value of my function. First, I've created a gradient function that depends on the external parameter d, which is given (see below).

```r
# Customers location from an external file (100 customers)
locations = read.csv(file = 'locations.csv')

# Gradient of my objective function is:
obj_fun.grad <- function(x,d) {
  dx <- 2*(x[1] - d$x)/((x[1] - d$x)^2 + 1) 
  dy <- 2*(x[2] - d$y)/((x[2] - d$y)^2 + 1)
  s <- c(sum(dx),sum(dy))

  return (s)
}
```

I then created my gradient descent function as below. I would like to keep this function as most generic as possible, so re-usable for other objective functions.

```r
grad.descent = function(grad.function, x0, max.iter=200, step.size=0.05, stopping.deriv=0.01,...) 
{
  # Calculating the length of the initial vector 
  n = length(x0) 

  # Create a matrix where the coordinates of different steps will be stored 
  xmat = matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=max.iter)
  # Initial guess is the starting point
  xmat[,1] = x0

  for (k in 2:max.iter) {

    # Calculate the gradient, that depends on locations of customers
    grad.cur = grad.function(xmat[,k-1], d=d)

    # Check whether gradient is below the given threshold
    if (sqrt(t(grad.cur)%*%grad.cur) < stopping.deriv) {
      k = k-1; 
      break
      }

    # Move in the opposite direction of the grad
    xmat[,k] = xmat[,k-1] - step.size*grad.cur
    }

  # Remove unused positions
  xmat = xmat[,1:k] 

  # Return: 1) optimum position, 2) list of all positions, 3) number of iterations
  return(list(x=xmat[,k], xmat=xmat[,1:k], k=k))
}
```

Now I would like to invoke the grad.descent function passing if the locations file as an additional parameter to be then passed to the gradient function:

`gd1 <- grad.descent(obj_fun, x0 = c(200,200), max.iter = 200, step.size=0.5, locations)`

However, I get the following error:

> Error in fgrad(xmat[, k - 1], d = d) : object 'd' not found

Comment: Please post your complete example. Probably you need to pass `d` to `grad.descent` too.

Comment: I think you just need to make it so `grad.descent` takes one extra argument, e.g. `grad.descent = function(f, x0, d, max.iter=200, <etc.>)`. Unless I'm missing something that makes this more complicated?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your help. I also thought about adding d as argument to the grad.descent function but I was wondering if it was possible to make it more generic :)

Comment: @Cettt d is what is contained in locations.csv. Thank you so much for your patience and support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R is telling you that the object `d` is not found because you never told it what `d` was.

The easiest way to fix it, is to replace the first line inside the for loop in the `grad.descent` function with the following line:

```
grad.cur = grad.function(xmat[,k-1], d = locations)
```

This way the function `grad.function` knows that it should take the dataframe `locations` as its second input `d`.

Note that this works because R uses *lexical scoping*. You can find more information [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lexical-scoping).

Comment: Thank you Cettt. I was wondering if there's a way for grad.descent function to accept some generic optional parameters to be used inside it. But I've got your solution.